# Make each element in a string list lowercase using Kotlin

Tags: list, loops, kotlin

I have the following function:

```
fun listToLowerCase(names: List<String>) {}
```

I wish to make the "names" list lowercase in-place something like:

```
names = names.map { it.lowercase() }
```

What would be the most efficient way to do it in Kotlin and why?

Comment: You already stated the answer in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify a `List<*>` in-place in Kotlin because this type represents read-only lists.

It's more common in Kotlin to use a functional approach for this and return a new `List`, instead. As you have stated, this can be accomplished with a simple `map { it.lowercase() }`.

If you really really want to do it in-place, you'll need to work with a `MutableList`:

```kotlin
fun listToLowerCase(names: MutableList<String>) {
    names.replaceAll(String::lowercase)
    // or depending on taste:
    // names.replaceAll { it.lowercase }
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```kotlin
val list = mutableListOf("Bob", "George", "FRED")
listToLowerCase(list) // mutates the list
println(list) // [bob, george, fred]
```

You wouldn't even really need a helper function for this, to be honest.

Comment: You can map in place with [replaceAll()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/replace-all.html). `names.replaceAll(String::lowercase)`

Comment: @Tenfour04 I worked so little with mutable structures I didn't even know there were helpers in the stdlib for this :D thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also define an extension:

```
// An extension function for List<String>:
fun List<String>.lowerCase(): List<String> = this.map { it.lowercase() }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
val lowerCaseList = listOf("Banana", "Pineapple", "Orange").lowerCase()
println(lowerCaseList)
```

In terms of efficiency, the `map` approach is very similar to using a `for loop`. And since it is definitely more redeable and less error prone, you should go with it.

Answer (score 1):

The following works. Why overthink the problems?

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val names = listOf("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")
    print(listToLowerCase(names))
}

fun listToLowerCase(names: List<String>): List<String> {
    return names.map { it.lowercase() }
}
```